# how to get fully qualified SQL type name in java to be used with CallableStatement.registerOutParameter

Tags: java, sql, types, qualified

Anyone know how to make a "fully-qualified name of an SQL structured type " tobe passed as an argument to [this function](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/CallableStatement.html#registerOutParameter%28int,%20int,%20java.lang.String%29):

```
public void registerOutParameter(int paramIndex,
                                 int sqlType,
                                 String typeName)
                          throws SQLException
```

Parameters:

- paramIndex - the first parameter is 1, the second is 2,...
- sqlType - a value from Types
- typeName - the fully-qualified name of an SQL structured type

Answer (score 0):

Java Object class has a getClass() method, it will return the Class of that object and toString() will give you the fully qualified class name.

```
String classname = myobj.getClass().toString()
```

while calling registerOutParameter() pass arguments like this,

```
public void registerOutParameter(1,2,myobj.getClass().toString())
```

Comment: String call="{call es_job.create_user_job(?,?)}";
CallableStatement Sstmt=(CallableStatement)conn.prepareCall( call);
// set the in param going into stored procedure only
Sstmt.setString(1, "some text");
// set the in param coming out of stored procedure only
Sstmt.registerOutParameter(3, java.sql.Types.CHAR, Sstmt.getClass().toString());
Sstmt.execute();
//rsJob = Sstmt.getString("jobid");
//System.out.println(rsJob + " " + rsJob.length());
Sstmt.close();

Comment: I have an oracle stored procedure that returns a char(5). I like to call this from java. Which one of the registerOutParameter functions of the CallableStatement can be used to get this char(5)?